# Am I a junior or senior front-end developer?

Tags: careers

I hope this is the right stackexchange site to this question... If not, please just vote to close.

My job position is something really new in the business field, before people like me was just called "web developer", but now a differentiation is necessary, because there's a specialization in specific fields of the web development.

I've worked professionally with HTML, CSS and JavaScript for about 5 years (starting from 2011). First using just vanilla JavaScript and jQuery, then, 2 years ago I've started with Node.js and for the past year I've heavily worked with front-end frameworks (mostly Ember.js).

In my specific field (HTML, JS and CSS) I think to have an extensive knowledge and usually I come up with a solution to any problem I face.

I'm just 23 tho, and everytime I sign a contract I get the "junior" title.

I know the informations I've provided are not a lot but I would like to understand if I'm a still a junior front-end developer or something else.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, job titles are pretty meaningless - although some people get very attached to them. How long you have worked with something is different from how many year's professional experience you have. A junior developer is often someone who as 2 or 3 years' professional experience, but again, that can be fairly arbitrary. People who are hiring you are more interested in your skills than your previous job titles.

Comment: How is your experience in comparison to your colleagues who don't have the "junior" title?

Comment: As I said, it varies from company to company, but Junior/Senior titles typically depend on number of years of professional experience rather than specific skill sets. Senior Developers are often expected to have other skills over and above technical proficiency that come from "years on the job".

Comment: When you find yourself answering more front end questions vs asking them you know you're closer to senior than junior. As far as titles being handed out, you need to ask if the position is looking for a junior or senior level front end designer. You're letting other people decide your fate, you should be deciding it.

Comment: How much guidance do you need? How much guidance do you give to others? Those are often the key distinctions between "ranks"... but for resume purposes strong examples of what you can do are far more useful than titles,

Answer (score 6):

A job title is not set in stone. It's not even standardized. You are what the company says you are. As everything else, you can negotiate that for your contract. In the end, it's meaningless though. It's just a given title.

You could found a company and call your developers "Senior Grandmaster of the Universe". You could still pay them peanuts and treat them badly. Look for a company that treats you well, your title is secondary at best.